# Dynamic Arrays Of Dynamic Objects

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to implement a simple Instructor List which is a dynamic array of dynamic"Instructor" objects. First of all I am **not allowed to use STL neither the vector etc**. The goal is start a dynamic instructor array on heap with a default value, and when need to add instructor, expand the arraysize if necessary. The problem is initializing the array of instructors with a default size is not possible because the Instructor object's size is dynamic also. Is there a nice way to handle this?

Here is the Instructor class

```
class Instructor{
private:
    string title, firstName, lastName, telNo, roomNo, userName, eMail;
    string courses[];

public:
    Instructor();
    Instructor(string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string);
    string getTitle();
    string getFirstName();
    string getLastName();
    string getTelNo();
    string getRoomNo();
    string getUserName();
    string getEMail();
    string getCourse(int courseIndex);
    void setTitle(string);
    void setFirstName(string);
    void setLastName(string);
    void setTelNo(string);
    void setRoomNo(string);
    void setUserName(string);
    void setEMail(string);
    void setCourse(string);
    void print();
};
```

The part that i try to initialize the array:

```
int size = 5;
Instructor *instructorList;
instructorList = new Instructor[size];
```

It throws the error: Type containing an unknown size array is not allowed

Comment: You already solved the problem for the `instructorList`. The `courses` list can use the same technique.

Comment: It compiles and runs perfectly fine. http://ideone.com/d7y0Qx

Comment: @BoPersson yeah that's right, the answer provides the same logic. Thanks!

Comment: @AnukulSangwan I guess something different works for visual studio 2013. Same code throws error because of the courses array is not initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pointer to store (the address of) the array.

Instead of

```
string courses[];
```

use

```
string *courses;
```

and initialize it like

```
courses = new string[size_of_elements];
```

To expand the number of elements, you will have to

1. Allocate new array with new size
2. Copy contents of old array to the new array
3. Destroy *only* the old array (do not destroy the new array here!)
4. Assign the address of the new array to `courses`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works just fine. So the problem is the compiler doesn't know that how many elements will be stored in courses array?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple example similar to your code. It works fine.

```
class A {
private:
    char *field;
public:
    A() {};
    A(char *field) : field(field) { }
    char *getField() const {
        return field;
    }
};

int main() {
    int size = 5;
    A *aList = new A[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        aList[i] = A((char *) std::to_string(i).c_str());
        std::cout << aList[i].getField();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use it to fix your error